# Google Chat on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery-plugins, chat

Is it possible or any plugins to use chat feature for community page on GAE. Something like gmail chat? maybe some Jquery driven chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to [Using Goole App Engine book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596522735).
Chapters 8\9 describe how to develop a basic Jquery chat with GAE, [here](http://www.appenginelearn.com/static/sample-appengine-apps.zip) you can download sources of the chapters and [here](http://vimeo.com/8066901) a live coding session.

Comment: @systempuntoout, yes this is fine example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [google-app-engine-samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/).  There is an app called [geochat](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/geochat) that might be a good reference app for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks James... One of good example also. I already try this but don't really meet my requirement since it use google map for user location while chat that are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check Applozic Chat plugin

https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin/
https://www.applozic.com/docs/web-chat-plugin.html

Disclaimer: I am from Applozic